# How can I wrap ad-serving javascript in a div on my Wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ads

There's a snippet of Javascript serving up ads on my website at http://digitl.co.nz

I want to format the space around the ad so it looks more separate from the main material. To do this I've wrapped the code in a div:

```
<div id="ad-break-out">
<script type='text/javascript'>
    GA_googleFillSlot("digitl_Super-Rectangle");
</script>
</div>
```

My problem is when I try to add CSS for the div in my WordPress child theme, it doesn't appear to get picked up.

```
#ad-break-out {}
```

I've tried it with the class and id selectors, but get the same effect with both - I suspect there's a problem with the end .

The same thing happens if I try to add CSS for the divs generated by the Javascript.

Comment: what css properties did you use?

Comment: I found the problem - in an unexpected place. When I added the CSS properties to the child theme CCS file, nothing happened. When I added the same properties using the CSS stylesheet editor from inside the WordPress dashboard, they worked fine.